# How to write ohm in paragraph in latex?

Tags: siunitx

How to write ohm in LaTeX? I was trying to write ohm like `\si{\ohm}`, but it did not work for me. I am getting error. Kindly explain how to write ohm.

Comment: Did you load the package to use `\si`? `\usepackage{siunitx}`. MWE: `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{siunitx}\begin{document}\si{\ohm}\end{document}`

Comment: how to load  a new pakage?

Comment: Did you tried the MWE above?

Comment: No i did not tried MWE

Comment: So, please, try to load that package as in MWE.

Comment: How to load this pakage.

Comment: As I wrote above: `\usepackage{siunitx}`. Consider also reading a very basic introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: Please tell us more about the error(s) you get when inputting `\si{\ohm}`.

Comment: If everything else fails, you could also try `$\Omega$`. However, it's *much better* to learn how to load the `siunitx` package, so that you can write `\si{\ohm}`.